# PHP & cURL Not Working with Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, rest, curl

I'm trying to create a web page to hit a web service (URL) but it doesn't appear to be working.

I'm able to verify connection as hitting the web service creates various log entries.  I am able to hit the URL directly from my browser and using curl from the command line successfully.

Here's my code.

```
$url = "https://example.com/webservice";
$ch = curl_init($url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/etc/my.pem");

$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r ($result);

$error = curl_error($ch);
print_r ($error);

$cinfo = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r ($cinfo);

curl_close($ch);
```

$result and $error return nothing.

Comment: In your code, should be `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST ` instead of `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOTS `. All work for me both on console or web. Problem may come from the certificate verification stuffs. Better you check your log file of your webserver to see what's wrong.

Comment: Yes that was a type-o.

Comment: You keep making wrong typo (not type-o) :) as well known in community. Okay did you find out what's wrong in your webserver log ?

Comment: LOL!  No I did not find anything in the logs yet.

Comment: I do see something in the error_log about Initializing NSS search path.  Not sure it's an error though.

Comment: Can you post the detail of error somewhere and put the link in your description ? I just do a search, it says about Firefox, are you working with Firefox ? Try with Chrome ?